# How can I set values going up by powers of $2$ in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code which will need values of $\sin(x)$ for $x = 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, \dots, 2^{25}$

Being fairly new at matlab still, I am unsure how to do this in the most efficient manner.

I know

```
n=0:10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But putting in something like

```
n = 2^2:2^x:2^25
```

Doesn't make sense, so what would be another way I could do this?

I suppose I could let

```
x=3:24
```

But where would I proceed for there?

Comment: You can do the following:

y=[2:25];

x=sin(2.^y);

PS: How can you put code text?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can in the comments,
but if you post an answer it will work if you highlight your text and click on the $\{ \}$ button

Comment: @CarlosLaguillo Backticks should work for inline code: `y=[2:25]; x=sin(2.^y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should work fine:

```
% Initiate the loop, i.e., the power of 2, from n=2 to n=25
for n = 2:25

    % Find the value of 2 raised to the power of n where n ranges from 2 to 25
    x = 2^n;

    % Evaluate the value of sin at x and store it in an array y (row vector)
    y(n) = sin(x); 
end
```

Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: thank you a lot!

I will give this a try and report back. Although it's not exactly sin(x) which I am computing so it may take a while for me to get back to you, as there is some other work ! :P

Comment: Hey @user56031 I just wanted to ask a follow up question.

I want to display the difference between y(n) and pi, but for EACH instance of n.

As of the moment, I have

disp(abs(y(n)-pi)), however this only gives me the error for the value at n=25, instead of n=1,2,3,...,25

Comment: Whoops! sorry, I think I got it.
I was writing that outside the for-loop, but then I moved the disp codes I wanted inside and it worked. nevermind!